# login on oracle database 12c release 2

Tags: database, oracle-12c

I am new with Oracle database. So I went ahead and installed Oracle database 12c release 2 following some instructions on youtube.

In another video tutorial I saw this where the he clicks on Password management button to change the password.

As I am using Oracle 12c release 2 I don't see this option.

[image]

I try to create a connection using Oracle sql developer, but can't seem to log in. Which account should I use to log in?

- SIP: orcl
- container: orclpdb
- Create and configure a database
- Desktop class

[image]

Where can I find the option to manage passwords as shown in the print screen above?

Answer (score 1):

`sysdba` user is not present in Oracle by default.

You should use **Username:** `sys`

And in the role, you should select **Role:** `SYSDBA` as Sam pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Which passwords did you change?.I assume sys and system?.

I see you're trying to login with sysdba user.In connection type set role to sysdba see image

[image: role]